Downloading Symbols Artifact generated by PublishSymbols@2 from Azure DevOps GUI is not possible
I'm trying to download my published symbols that contain my c++ project .PDBs in Azure DevOps GUI but it is not giving me the possibility to do so. Am I missing something ?
I went to the pipeline published symbols :
the pipeline run
I found the symbols but not able to download them:
published symbols
My Yaml is as follows:
- task: PublishSymbols@2
    displayName: 'Publish symbols'
    inputs:
      SymbolsFolder: '$(myApp.build.dir)\$(Build.SourceBranchName)\Build\'
      SearchPattern: '**/*.*'
      IndexSources: true
      PublishSymbols: true
      SymbolServerType: 'TeamServices'
      SymbolExpirationInDays: '36530'
      SymbolsMaximumWaitTime: 99999
      SymbolsProduct: myApp
      DetailedLog: true
      SymbolsArtifactName: 'Symbols_BuildNumber_$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    condition: succeeded()

notice that the PDB files exist and are found correctly by the task since I can download them from a shared storage outside azure devops.
thanks

Couldn't you publish the PDB files as regular artifacts? AFAICS all the "publish symbols" step does is ingest the PDB files into azure devops' symbol server...

I didn't try since my app is a small repo inside a much larger project so I don't have full access to every thing. but @BrightRan-MSFT 's answer helped me to debug using the same pdb that I couldn't download. thanxs to you all

There is no any way to download the published symbols from Azure Artifacts symbol server via Azure DevOps web UI, REST API or CLI.
The symbol servers can enable the debugger to automatically retrieve the correct symbol files without knowing product names, build numbers, or package names.
You can follow the steps mentioned in "Symbols - Set up Visual Studio" to configure your Visual Studio to connect to the Azure Artifacts symbol server so that you can use Visual Studio to consume the published symbols from the Azure Artifacts symbol server.

